# How to verify a gpg signed file

Tags: gnupg

I was trying to install the newest version of libpcap (as the version in the repositories doesn't seem current) and ran into the following problem. I copied the `tcpdump-workers.asc` text from the tcpdump website (which hosts libpcap as well) and imported the key to my keyring using

```
gpg --import tcpdump-workers.asc
```

That when all well and fine but when I tried to verify the `libpcap-1.4.0.tar.gz` file against the key with `gpg --verify`, I ended up getting the message that `unexpected data`. was found. I am wondering if anyone else has run into this problem as the ancient technique of googling my problem has done little to answer my question.

Comment: Could you include the full command you used to verify the `libpcap-1.4.0.tar.gz` file? It looks like you're not using the `stdin` pipe correctly. Also include the exact and complete error message (copy & paste!) and the exact URL where you downloaded the tarball and key from (link to it please!). **Edit** your question to provide all this information.

Answer (score 5):

It depends which file you used to verify the signature. I try to describe the steps to verify it:

1. Download the signing key of the TCPdump group: `tcpdump-workers.asc`.

   ```
   wget http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump-workers.asc
   ```
2. Import the key to GnuPG:

   ```
   gpg --import tcpdump-workers.asc
   ```
3. Download the `libpcap` release and the signature:

   ```
   wget http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.4.0.tar.gz{,.sig}
   ```
4. Verify the signature:

   ```
   gpg --verify libpcap-1.4.0.tar.gz.sig libpcap-1.4.0.tar.gz
   ```

The last command should output something like:

```
gpg: Signature made Mon May 20 18:26:04 2013 CEST using RSA key ID D9C15D0D
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: Good signature from "The Tcpdump Group (Package signing key) <release@tcpdump.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

The 3rd line says that GnuPG considers the signature as good.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without importing the public key? Like `--no-default-keyring --keyring /path/to/pubkey.asc`?